# Javascript: TypeError: a is undefined - what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an array containing several markers for my googlemap.
When I try to add this array to my map I get this error. Any ideas why?

Here is my code:

```
    markers = [];
    function create_station_marker(position){
          if(position != null){
            eval(position);
            var latitude = parseFloat(position.latitude);
            var longitude = parseFloat(position.longitude);

            var new_icon = new GIcon();
            new_icon.image = "marker.png";
            new_icon.size = new GSize(25,17);
            var opt;
            opt = {};
            opt.icon = new_icon;

            var marker = new GMarker(new GLatLng(latitude, longitude),opt);
            markers.push(marker);
        }
    }
```

And this is where I add my Array to the map:

```
    function load_googlemap() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(48.092757,11.645508), 4);
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());


        for (var i=0; i< markers.length; i++ ) {
            try{
                map.addOverlay(markers[i]);
                alert(markers[i].toSource());

            }catch(ex){
                //here I get this error!!!
                alert(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Past complete example with some sample data please.

Comment: In my html view I do:

<pre class="prettyprint">
<script type="text/javascript">create_station_marker($position );</script>
</pre>
for each point (foreach).

on document.ready I call my load_googlemap() function.

Comment: does your html have an element with an id of "map" ?

Comment: Maybe you want to change API version to 3..

Comment: There's no reason to use eval. Use a JSON library.

Answer (score 1):

If `position` is a string containing a JSON representation of the data, you'd have to assign the result of `eval()` to another variable, e.g.:

```
if(position != null){
    position = eval(position);
    // ...
```

You should, however, parse it properly:

```
if(position != null){
    position = JSON.parse(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

i would inspect that "position" parameter  content once you have an eval over it, it could be the source of error